# Retrieve listview data from firebase with headers

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, android-adapter

i've put it below the array adapter but it didn't respond am getting error at this line: adapter.add((String) dataSnapshot.getValue()); 
ClassCastException java.util.Hashmap cannot be cast to java.lang.String Where should i put the codes specifically?

public class about extends Fragment {

```
ListView aboutList;

private ArrayList<String> items;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.about, container, false);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about, container, false);
    aboutList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.aboutus);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1);

    aboutList.setAdapter(adapter);


    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference aboutRef = rootRef.child("about");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String key = ds.getKey();
                Log.d("TAG", key);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    aboutRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
    rootRef.child("About").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            adapter.add((String) dataSnapshot.getValue());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    return v;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    getActivity().setTitle("About");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference aboutRef = rootRef.child("about");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            Log.d("TAG", key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
aboutRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

The output will be:

```
Departament
Fondation
Objectif
```

Comment: In your MainActivity.class and see the results in the logcat.

Comment: Ok, try to add it to your fragmnet. Does it work?

Comment: But you didn't use my code at all.  Add the code above and try again.

Comment: Replace your code with this one. It will worked, it's tested. What was the error?

Comment: Only the code that you using to get the data.

Comment: nothing is being displayed , the headers are being called but the title are not being called.

Comment: I tried to help but I recommend you learn at least the basics of Java.

Comment: yes, thanks a lot for your help man!